# Isometries of $R^3$

Tags: differential-geometry

Verify that the mapping $F:R^3 \to R^3$ defined by $F(x,y,z)= \frac 13(-2x+2y-z+6, 2x+y-2z+3, x+2y+2z-9)$ is a isometry 
 How do I find this isometry? Definition of isometry: An isometry of a mapping $F:R^3 \to R^3$ such that $d(F(p), F(q))=d(p,q)$ for all points $p$, $q$ in $R^3$ 
 By the definition of isometries, should I find its magnitude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance between $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ is $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2 + (z_1-z_2)^2}.$

Use that same formula to find the distance between $F(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $F(x_2,y_2,z_2),$ and see if it's the same.

**PS:** The distance from $F(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ to $F(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ is this: $$ \sqrt{ \begin{array}{r} \left( \dfrac {-2x_1+2y_1-z_1+6} 3 - \dfrac {-2x_2+2y_2-z_2+6} 3 \right)^2 \\[6pt] {} + \left( \dfrac {\phantom{-}2x_1+y_1-2z_1+3} 3 - \dfrac{\phantom{-}2x_2+y_2-2z_2+3} 3 \right)^2 \\[6pt] {} + \left( \dfrac {\phantom{-}x_1+2y_1 + 2z_1-9} 3 - \dfrac {\phantom{-}x_2+2y_2 + 2z_2-9} 3 \right)^2 \end{array}} $$ Simplify that and see if you get $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2 + (z_1-z_2)^2}.$

The important thing to understand is why *that* proves it's an isometry.

Comment: My $x_1$ and $ x_2$ is -2x and 2x?

Comment: I got 4 for my answer

Comment: @behold : $$\begin{align} F(x_1,y_1,z_1) & = \frac 13(-2x_1+2y_1-z_1+6, 2x_1+y_1-2z_1+3, x_1+2y_1 + 2z_1-9) \\ & = (u_1,v_1,w_1), \\ \\ F(x_2,y_2,z_2) & = \frac 13(-2x_2+2y_2-z_2+6, 2x_2+y_2-2z_2+3, x_2+2y_2 + 2z_2-9) \\ & = (u_2,v_2,w_2).  \end{align}$$ So find the distance between $(u_1,v_1,w_1)$ and $(u_2,v_2,w_2)$ and see if it's the same as the distance between $(x_1,y_2,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2). \qquad$

Comment: Ok I did the distance between $F(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $F(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and I got 2. Am I right this time?

Comment: @behold : If it's an isometry and you find the distance between $F(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $F(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, you should get the same thing as the distance between $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, i.e. you should get $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2 + (z_1-z_2)^2}.$ You shouldn't get $2$ unless you've plugged in some special values for the variables. $\qquad$

Comment: I got $\frac 23$ for $x_1$ and $-\frac 23$ for $x_2$. I took the magnitude of those values

Comment: same for $y_1$ and $y_2$

Comment: If it is another way to go about this, then I am all ears

Comment: See my PS added to the answer. It's an isometry if it preverves the distances between ALL pairs of points, not just between ONE pair of points, so what you're doing when you plug in particular numbers is not enough. $\qquad$

Comment: ok. I will adjust for all points. thanks

Comment: how do you simplify it?

Comment: $$ \sqrt{ \begin{array}{r} \left( \dfrac {-2x_1+2y_1-z_1+6} 3 - \dfrac {-2x_2+2y_2-z_2+6} 3 \right)^2 \\ \\ {} + \left( \dfrac {\phantom{-}2x_1+y_1-2z_1+3} 3 - \dfrac{\phantom{-}2x_2+y_2-2z_2+3} 3 \right)^2 \\  \\ {} + \left( \dfrac {\phantom{-}x_1+2y_1 + 2z_1-9} 3 - \dfrac {\phantom{-}x_2+2y_2 + 2z_2-9} 3 \right)^2 \end{array}} $$ The first thing I'd do is cancel the $6$s in the first term, then $3$s in the second term and the $-9$s in the third term. $\qquad$

Comment: $\cdots\cdots\,$getting this: $$\sqrt{ \begin{array}{r} \left( \dfrac {-2x_1+2y_1-z_1} 3 - \dfrac {-2x_2+2y_2-z_2} 3 \right)^2 \\ \\ {} + \left( \dfrac {\phantom{-}2x_1+y_1-2z_1} 3 - \dfrac{\phantom{-}2x_2+y_2-2z_2} 3 \right)^2 \\  \\ {} + \left( \dfrac {\phantom{-}x_1+2y_1 + 2z_1} 3 - \dfrac {\phantom{-}x_2+2y_2 + 2z_2} 3 \right)^2 \end{array}}$$

Comment: Then pull out the $1/3,$ getting this: $$ \frac 1 3 \sqrt{ \begin{array}{r} ((-2x_1+2y_1-z_1) - (-2x_2+2y_2-z_2))^2 \\ {} + ((2x_1+y_1-2z_1) - (2x_2+y_2-2z_2))^2 \\ {} + ((x_1+2y_1 + 2z_1) - (x_2+2y_2 + 2z_2))^2 \end{array}}$$

Comment: Then recall that $(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 +b^2 + c^2 + 2ab + 2ac+ 2bc$. Apply that to all three squares, then collect like terms.

Comment: $$ \begin{align} & \Big((-2x_1+2y_1-z_1) - (-2x_2+2y_2-z_2)\Big)^2 \\ \\ = {} & (-2x_1+2y_1-z_1)^2 + (-2x_2+2y_2-z_2)^2 - 2(-2x_1+2y_1 -z_1)(-2x_2+2y_2 -z_2) \\ \\ = {} & \Big( 4x_1^2 + 4y_1^2 + z_1^2 -8x_1y_1 +4 x_1 z_1 - 4y_1z_1\Big) + \Big(4x_2^2 + 4y_2^2 + z_2^2 -8x_2y_2 +4 x_2 z_2 - 4y_2z_2 \Big) \\  & {}-8x_1x_2 +8x_1y_2-4x_1 z_1 -8y_1 x_2 -8y_1 y_2 +4y_1z_2 -4z_1 x_2 +4z_1 y_2 -2z_1z_2 \end{align} $$ That's the first square. Do the other two the same way. $\qquad$